# Categories of abstract noun

Tags: abstract-nouns, word-class

What are the categories or types of abstract nouns? Or Are there categories or types of abstract nouns?

I think some categories are probably action noun or action, emotion, idea, condition, state or event.

Do more categories or types of abstract noun exist?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an exhaustive list, as you could group some together under one term or continue to break them down further. But in addition to those you mention, I would add:

- Human qualities or characteristics (eg 'confidence', ego). These are different from emotions or feelings.
- Social constructs (eg 'crime', 'ownership')
- Relative concepts (eg 'privilege')

Comment: I was thinking that maybe we might have more categories of abstract noun and I think I'm not understanding some categories. In what category would 'thought' be if 'thought' is an abstract noun?

Comment: And what is "relative concept", "social construct", or "human quality or characteristic"?

Comment: @user6779864  You mentioned "idea" in your question. That's really the same as thought.

Comment: I was thinking "thought" can be "action" or "mental action" too.